# DNS requests made for an HTTPS website don't go through dnsmasq

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, linux-networking, dnsmasq

I'm trying to set up dnsmasq to block some websites, but it only works when accessing that site via http and not when accessing it via https.

Is it somehow not possible to block https requests via dnsmasq?

Comment: DNS doesn't care whether you are accessing site over HTTP or HTTPS, because DNS resolution is done before starting web session.

Answer (score 1):

Dnsmasq provides Domain Name System (DNS) forwarder, Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) server.

So dnsmasq can not block http and https.

Comment: **DNS** is capable to perform translation of domain names like **serverfault.com --> 151.101.65.69**. The programm requesting this translation then uses the IP address to perform further action. Please be aware that this is not a security feature because DNS server at clients computers might be changed. Your should maybe lookup **DNS Blackhole** and **Proxy**.

Comment: I know this, but it's what's actually happening... requests for http websites are being logged and https website requests are not